# Correctly mapping rails url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller in a subdirectory called fridges (the higher-level directory it is in is called categories). I have made an index page for the fridges controller and it works correctly when I navigate to "categories/fridges/index". However, it doesn't work when browsing to 'categories/fridges' as I want it to.

Here is how it is being routed in the route config:

map.namespace :categories do |categories|
    categories.resources :fridges
end

What should I be doing to make the index page appear when navigating to the url 'categories/fridges' ?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, you can do:

```
  namespace 'category' do
    match '/fridges' => 'fridges#index'
    resources :fridges
  end
```

A similar approach can be taken for Rails 2.x. What you are looking for is the **match '/fridges' => 'fridges#index'**, which should be defined in your namespace.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Rails 3. When navigating to that url I get the message "The action 'show' could not be found for CategoriesController"